# quickSort in Mark Allen Weiss' book

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, quicksort

Function Median is to return the median of the left, right, and center elements.

```
template<typename Comparable>
const Comparable Median(vector<Comparable> & array, int left, int right)
{
    int center = (left + right) / 2;
    if (array[left] > array[right])
        swap(array[left], array[right]);
    if (array[center] > array[right])
        swap(array[center], array[right]);
    if (array[left] > array[center])
        swap(array[left], array[center]);
    swap(array[center], array[right - 1]);

    return array[right - 1];
}
```

In

```
1 template<typename Comparable>
2 void quickSort(vector<Comparable>& array, int left, int right)
3 {
4   int range = right - left + 1;
5   if (range > 10) // cutoff = 10
6   {
7       Comparable pivot = Median(array, left, right);
8       // partition
9       int i = left; int j = right - 1;
10      while (i < j)
11      {
12          while (array[++i] < pivot);
13          while (array[--j] > pivot);
14          swap(array[i], array[j]);
15      }
16      swap(array[i], array[right - 1]);
17      // recursion
18      quickSort(array, left, i - 1);
19      quickSort(array, i + 1, right);
20  }
21
22  else
23      insertionSort(array, left, right);
24 };
```

replace lines 9 to 15 with the statements as follows

```
    int i = left + 1, j = right - 2;
    for (; ; )
    {
        while (a[i] < pivot) i++;
        while (pivot < a[j]) j--;
        if (i < j)
            std::swap(a[i], a[j]);
        else
            break;
    }
```

here is the part I can't understand:

> after replacement, this does not work, because there would be an
> inﬁnite loop if a[i] = a[j] = pivot.

*Why* would it lead to an infinite loop?

Comment: Did you check the replaced code with your debugger? At which point does `i < j` start to change nevermore?

Comment: `Why would it lead to an infinite loop?` - because `i` and `j` don't change in that scenario, so `break` could never be reached - or was that not the real question?

Comment: thanks @500 - Internal Server Error ,  it is a easy problem

Comment: What the author wants to express should be: first increase and then check, not first check and then increase, the latter will make i, j unable to increase, which will lead to an infinite loop